# filter data according to months

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-formatting

I'm building query which filter data according to months using **created_at** column, my current query

**Query:**

`SELECT id, title, body, created_at, from posts  ORDER BY id DESC`

Now when created_at column prints it shows following result **2020-03-01 07:50:07** but i want to print month name like **March,April** 
how it should be achieved

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query:**

```
SELECT id, title, body, MONTHNAME(created_at) from posts  ORDER BY id DESC
```

replace **created_at** with **MONTHNAME(created_at)**

MONTHNAME(col_name) function will display month name

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [MySQL date function `MONTHNAME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname):

```
SELECT id, title, body, MONTHNAME(created_at) created_month
FROM posts  
ORDER BY id DESC
```